# How to arrange the digits of a number such that when I break it into two numbers of equal digits the product of the two numbers is maximum?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, permutation

*Example: If I take the number 4544, then the maximum product I get is 2376 when I rearrange the digits as 5444.
(54 x 44) = 2376 which is greater than (45 x 44) = 1980*

My approach for solving the problem was to permute the number in all possible ways, divide it into two parts and then find the max product from there. Is there a faster way to solve the problem or is a completely different approach to the problem is possible?

Here's my code:

```java
 import java.util.*;
class MaxProduct
{
    static int maxprod = 0;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a no");
    String n = sc.next();
    permute(n,0);
    System.out.println("Max Product is "+maxprod);
    }
    public static void permute(String s,int i)
    {
             if( i==s.length()-1)
         {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,i/2+1));
            int b = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i/2+1));
            maxprod = Math.max(a*b,maxprod);
         }
            else 
            {
            for(int k=i;k<s.length();k++)
                {
                          s =swapelement(s,k,i); 
                          permute(s,i+1);
                          s=swapelement(s,k,i);
            }
            }
    }
       public static String swapelement(String a,int i, int j)
            {
                char x[]=a.toCharArray();
                char ch = x[i];
                x[i]=x[j];
                x[j]=ch;
                return String.valueOf(x);
            }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us the code of your solution.   (For what it is worth, if you have a solution to a puzzle that runs in a practical amount of time, you don't *need* a faster solution.  Unless this is a homework exercise and they *require* the fastest possible solution for maximum marks.  And even then, you possibly shouldn't be asking for help like this ...)

Comment: This is not a homework exercise and I am not only interested in a faster solution, I would also like to know if there is a different approach to the problem than mine. That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at a smaller problem first. For variables `x,y`, you are given

```
x + y = c (constant)
```

The question is, when will `x*y` be maximum? It can be solved in many ways, one of them being [differential math](https://qr.ae/pvyjEP). Long story short, the closer `x` and `y` are to each other, the larger their product is.

#### How to apply this to your problem?

1. Take the largest digits in the set, assign them to the numbers (let them be `A` and `B`)
2. As soon as one number becomes bigger than the other (let `A>B`), assign the remaining digits to maximise `B` (larger digits in descending order). For `A` we use the remaining smaller digits to make the largest number out of them. Assigning the larger digits to `B` is done to make it closer to `A`.

###### Example #1

Number = 123456
Taking largest digits, `A = 6 and B = 5`. Now, we will greedily maximise `B`, so the numbers become `A = 621 and B = 543`

###### Example #2

Number = 88871256
Taking largest digits, `A = 8 and B = 8`. Since they're still equal, we repeat step 1, so `A = 88 and B = 87`.  Now, we will greedily maximise `B`, so the numbers become `A = 8821 and B = 8765`.

Since this is a rather straightforward problem, adding any implementation seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

One approach can be two find two highest digits, and keeping them in the left most place and than do the opposite for remaining 2nd place.

for example:

if you have number 1234, the highest digits are 3 and 4 so lets keep them on first position, and for remaining 2 do the same so numbers will be:

(41*32) = 1312

so here you see 1312 is highest number possible

Comment: So what exactly would I do for 123456?